# 'private: true' and 'lsd: false' not recognised as valid torrent options, won't allow torrent to be converted to private. NodeJS | WebTorrent

Tags: node.js, webrtc, torrent, webtorrent

**What version of this package are you using?**

webtorrent@0.107.17

webtorrent-hybrid@4.0.2

**What operating system, Node.js, and npm version?**
OS: Linux Lite 5 (64 bit)

Node.js: 14.15.1

npm: 6.14.8

**What happened?**

I normally initialised a client by following the docs. Like so:

`this.webTorrentClient = new WebTorrentHybrid({tracker: true, dht: true});`

However, I simply wanted to switch my torrent to private so that it won't publish to DHT, PEX and LSD. I specifically have a requirement to disable LSD. Again I followed the docs, added opts and put in the private flag like so:

```
this.webTorrentClient.add(magnetUri, {private: true}, (torrent) => {
        //did my task here
      });
```

On doing that weirdly I was greeted with this error stating that this particular property doesn't exist in torrent options

```
Argument of type '{ private: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TorrentOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'private' does not exist in type 'TorrentOptions'
```

On facing this error, I initially figured that maybe opts for WebTorrentHybrid are different from WebTorrent but when I fetched the docs they stated that it's exactly the same. I then tried putting `private: true` in the `.seed` method instead, but received the same error.

Alternatively I figured, that since I only want LSD to be disabled and digging through the commit history I found that an option to disable LSD has also been added. (With reference to this commit ID here: https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent/commit/0ba67b8e8f54d888ba0dd14a6e5f4a18d46e1294). So I tried putting `lsd: false` in both `.add` and `.seed` but again no dice. Same error.

At this point I felt that maybe I am passing opts in the wrong format but on trying other opts. They worked just fine. I tried putting `path: '/mnt/drive1/'` in both `.add` and `.seed` like so:

```
this.webTorrentClient.add(magnetUri, {path: '/mnt/drive1/'}, (torrent) => {
        //did my task here
      });
```

And it worked absolutely fine, similarly I tried `maxWebConns: 3` and that too worked! For some reason only private and lsd don't seem to be working in my case. Quick google search showed that no one else had a similar problem and I was left confused!

I have been following the official docs from here: https://webtorrent.io/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue. I solved the above issue by manually updating the following packages by using these commands:

```
npm update --save/--save-dev
npm install webtorrent@latest --save-dev
npm install @types/webtorrent@latest --save-dev
```

I had in my quest to solve this issue, run `npm update --save/--save-dev` several times. But for some reason these packages hadn't been updated even when there weren't any breaking changes. Realising they were outdated by running `npm outdated` and then manually updating by using the commands above solved it!